# Most probable probability distribution given outcome

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given several values of x that are outcomes of a random experiment and a parametric model of the probability, what is a sensible way to choose the parameters?

Does it make sense to optimize the overlap integral of the model and the outcome?

How can a prior knowledge be considered, should the entropy be maximized?

For example:
The model is a distribution that consists of two gaussians:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\,N{(μ_1,σ_1)}+\frac{1}{2}\,N{(μ_1,σ_1)}
$$
and the outcome could be:

0 1 0 3 4 4

And the prior knowledge could be that $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Bayes Statistics help me.
First have some estimate of the parameters and then update them until convergence like done with Expectation Maximization.
In the case of a gaussian mixture modell like in the example there already are plenty implementations available.